# Как добавить скроллбары в кастомный RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, usercontrol, richtextbox

Создаю свою компоненту richtextbox. Не могу понять как добавить вертикальный скроллбар?

```
 class ViewOnlyRichTextBox : RichTextBox
    {
        const int WM_SETFOCUS = 0x0007;
        const int WM_KILLFOCUS = 0x0008;

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == WM_SETFOCUS) m.Msg = WM_KILLFOCUS;

            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Встроенными средствами Windows Forms этого сделать нельзя. Однако WinAPI (поверх которого и построен WF) позволяет добавить полосу прокрутки к элементу управления без вмешательства в его содержимое и даже создания экземпляра `ScrollBar`.

Дело в том, что в WinAPI каждое окно и каждый элемент управления уже имеют вертикальную и горизонтальную полосы прокрутки, и надо просто попросить операционную систему их показать. Делается это с помощью задания флагов *оконного стиля* `WS_HSCROLL` и `WS_VSCROLL` для горизонтальной и вертикальной полос прокрутки соответственно.

Эти стили задаются через свойство [`CreateParams`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.createparams.aspx). Так как оно доступно только для чтения, переопределим его (благо, оно виртуальное):

```
class ViewOnlyRichTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    // ...

    const int WS_HSCROLL = 0x00100000;
    const int WS_VSCROLL = 0x00200000;
    const int WM_HSCROLL = 0x0114;
    const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x0115;
    const int SB_HORZ    = 0;
    const int SB_VERT    = 1;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetScrollPos(IntPtr hwnd, int nBar);

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
        get {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.Style |= WS_VSCROLL;
            return cp;
        }
    }
}
```

Эти полосы прокрутки генерируют `WndProc`-сообщения `WM_HSCROLL` и `WM_VSCROLL` при любой горизонтальной и вертикальной прокрутке соответственно. Конкретное положение ползунков можно получить при помощи [`GetScrollPos(this.Handle, ...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/bb787585.aspx), где вместо многоточия надо подставить либо `SB_HORZ`, либо `SB_VERT` для указания на интересующую нас полосу.